# Instagram API to fetch email

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I need to integrate Instagram API to fetch user's details like username and email and need to save these information for the user,
i read the below link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api

but this does not fetch the email id of the user,
i also read below link but it also does not provide email of the user:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api

If any body can reply, that will be helpful,
Thanks

Comment: what makes you believe that this is possible? the api reference does not mention the email in the fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user

Comment: @andyrandy exactly that's what i am asking here, as i did not find any thing yet to get the user's email after authenticating the user successfully from instagram api

Answer (score -1):

That's a privacy issue to be able to fetch user's email and other information I think you would need to create an app that allows sign in or login then get any user that had signed in to your app, details for example if I sign in to your app you would need to get my email address you can do that using a simple database tool then convert that into an API by performing a post request once data has being sent to the database.

Comment: Sorry i could not understand your answer, let me clear the problem for you, i have to signup the users on my website using instagram login, so i have integrated the instagram api to get the access token, which can be used to get the user's detail, now using this access_token i need to get the user email as this is required in our system, but in instagram api i did not find any solution to get the email of the user, like i can get the username of the user but not email

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).